# Restore missing vowels in an array of words

Tags: javascript, deep-learning, neural-network, nlp

I have an array of item descriptions, many of which have had some vowels removed from some words. What is the best approach for replacing them, using javascript?

Many answers on here about how to remove vowels, but I can't find anything on how to restore them?

Complete accuracy is not a requirement, a best-guess would be good enough?

Comment: Adding deep learning related tags for you. Since there's no way to know `dck` stands for `duck` or `deck` without context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of any ready-to-use solution, but you can easily train a neural network for that yourself.

This can be formulated as a sequence labeling problem. You need to label every character in the sequence with a flag telling what vowel should be added after the character (or none eventually).

You can easily prepare synthetic training data for the task: just take any English text, randomly drop vowels and generate the ground truth labels on the fly. A suitable architecture is a lightweight bidirectional LSTM (my guess is 64 hidden units are enough) with a simple classifier on top.

The easiest way to have the model in JavaScript is training the model in TensorFlow in Python and then [convert the model TensorFlow.js](https://www.tensorflow.org/js/guide/conversion).

Comment: Ok - there's some reading and research there for me. Thank you :) It's difficult to know where to start with ML stuff, but this seems like a nice problem to get started with. Thank you again for the guidance!